# Limit not giving expected result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am taking the limit

```
Limit[Sin[π Sqrt[4 n^2 + n]], n -> ∞]
```

the returned answer is

```
Interval[{-1, 1}]
```

I think the right answer is $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

I am using 10.0. What is happening?

Comment: Compare `DiscretePlot[Sin[\[Pi] Sqrt[4 n^2 + n]], {n, 0, 100}]` with `Plot[Sin[\[Pi] Sqrt[4 n^2 + n]], {n, 0, 100}]`

Comment: Hi Artes they say here: http://www.mathisfunforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=338773#p338773

Comment: @bobbym They are considering a discreet variable, while Mma considers the `Limit[]` var as continous

Comment: How do you know that they are considering a discrete variable, is it because it says sequence limit?

Comment: Your question is ill posed, you assume that `n` is neccesarily integer but you don't put your assumption to your formula.

Comment: Hi Artes how should I have realized that n is an integer?

Comment: @bobbym There is no limit if you take a real valued argument because between `n` and `n+1` the argument takes all real values and then the function gives all real numbers between `-1` and `1`. You could put your problem this way ; `Limit[Sin[Pi Sqrt[4 n^2 + n]], n -> Infinity, 
 Assumptions -> n \[Element] Integers]` and it returns the desired value.

Comment: @Artes, I hear you, thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to tell *Mathematica* explicitly that `n` is supposed to be an integer:

```
Assuming[n ∈ Integers, Limit[Sin[π Sqrt[4 n^2 + n]], n -> ∞]]
(*
==> 1/Sqrt[2]
*)
```

Comment: Nice! I'm sure I've tried that in the past and it didn't work

Comment: I didn't think that would work either..

Comment: @Daniel This kind of violation of expectations has happened many times in the past.  It shows that there is a lot of room for improvement here: either in the way this functionality is accessed, or in the documentation.  Several of us looked at this question and it never occurred to most of us that this might work. (It already works in v8.)  The documentation mentions nothing about this, but even if it did, it would be hard to discover ... It would appear that Limit has separate cases for sequences and continuous limits.  This should be very clearly explained under Details in the documentation.

Comment: @Daniel There are so many things like this in Mathematica, even the relatively known `Integrate[Boole[...] ..., ...]` is practically undocumented outside examples and would be hard to discover for someone who doesn't participate on forums like this and doesn't see a lot of Mathematica code every day.  It's really a separate functionality that's hidden under the meta-function "Integrate".  It would be a pity for these gems to be lost just because they're so hard to discover.

Comment: @Szabolcs I think that use of `Assuming` of integrality in `Limit` works more or less by accident. I would not want to document a behavior I had no reason to think was reliable.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a way to use Mathematica to find **numerical** limits for discrete variables:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
u = IntegerPart;
NLimit[Sin[Pi Sqrt[4 u[n]^2 + u@n]], n -> ∞]
(* 0.707107 *)
```

Comment: I was aware of NLimit but I just thought it used a numerical method to get a function limit. I did not realize as your plots show that the two limits are different.

Comment: Note that there appears to be a bug in `Limit` since `Limit[Sin[Pi Sqrt[4 IntegerPart[n]^2 + IntegerPart[n]]], n-> Infinity]` returns the wrong answer `Interval[{-1,1}]`.